# Mark.js not scrolling to next result when inside a scrollable div/table

Tags: jquery, search, highlight

I am using minicss framework with jquery and mark.js to build a responsive, one-page, searchable owner's manual.

I am trying to use the mark.js script with search bar highlighting to cycle through results on one single page.

Everything works fine until it finds a result that is INSIDE one of the scrollable table divs.

Similar to this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/

and here is the code I am using in header for the mark.js :

```
window.onload=function(){

$(function() {

  // the input field
  var $input = $("input[type='search']"),
    // clear button
    $clearBtn = $("button[data-search='clear']"),
    // prev button
    $prevBtn = $("button[data-search='prev']"),
    // next button
    $nextBtn = $("button[data-search='next']"),
    // the context where to search
    $content = $(".content2"),
    // jQuery object to save <mark> elements
    $results,
    // the class that will be appended to the current
    // focused element
    currentClass = "current",

    // top offset for the jump (the search bar)
    offsetTop = 70,
    // the current index of the focused element
    currentIndex = 0;

  /**
   * Jumps to the element matching the currentIndex
   */
  function jumpTo() {
    if ($results.length) {
      var position,
        $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
      $results.removeClass(currentClass);

      if ($current.length) {
        $current.addClass(currentClass);


          position = $current.offset().top - offsetTop;
        //window.scrollTo(0, position);

      //var currentmark = getElementsByClassName('current');

          //var tab = getElementsByClassName('scrollable striped');
         var doc = document.getElementById('doc-content');

         var element = document.getElementsByClassName('current');



          //var menu = getElementById('nav-drawer');

            //menu.scrollTo(0, position);
          //tab.scrollTo(0, position);
            //tab.scrollTo(0, position);

    element.scrollTo(0, position);

          doc.scrollTo(0, position);


        //element.scrollIntoView(true);  

         //window.scrollTo(0, position);



      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Searches for the entered keyword in the
   * specified context on input
   */
  $input.on("input", function() {
    var searchVal = this.value;
    $content.unmark({
      done: function() {
        $content.mark(searchVal, {
          separateWordSearch: true,

          done: function() {
            $results = $content.find("mark");
            currentIndex = 0;
            jumpTo();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  /**
   * Clears the search
   */
  $clearBtn.on("click", function() {
    $content.unmark();
    $input.val("").focus();
  });

  /**
   * Next and previous search jump to
   */
  $nextBtn.add($prevBtn).on("click", function() {
    if ($results.length) {
      currentIndex += $(this).is($prevBtn) ? -1 : 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = $results.length - 1;
      }
      if (currentIndex > $results.length - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      jumpTo();
    }
  });
});


    }
```

I have tried adding

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('current');

element.scrollTo(0, position);
```

in the jumpto() script,  right BEFORE it scrolls the main window, however it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: by the way, I have used this site for years to troubleshoot my code and find answers and this is the first time I havent found an answer, glad to finally be able to contribute a question!  please inform me if I have not done anything right!

Comment: does anyone know a way to hide the url I gave above? i don't want uncle g****le to find it if you know what I mean....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited, you need to scroll the `table` find it parent using `.closest()` and the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x4knog19/)

```
function jumpTo() {
  if ($results.length) {
    var position,
      $current = $results.eq(currentIndex);
    $results.removeClass(currentClass);
    if ($current.length) {
      $current.addClass(currentClass);
      var parent = $current.closest('table')
      if (parent.length) {
        $('html').scrollTop(parent.offset().top - offsetTop)
        parent.scrollTop(parent.scrollTop() - parent.offset().top + $current.offset().top);
      }
      else {
        $('html').animate({
          scrollTop: $current.offset().top - offsetTop
        }, 300);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that works great, for the first table,  until going to the next table,  then page stops scrolling again...   so  according to this code we are identifying the nearest table as the parent,  then scrolling to it?

Comment: by the way I am testing this by searching the word  'and'  which has plenty of results for testing...   it works so good until we go PAST the first scrollable table.   thanks for any further help you can provide you rock!!!

Comment: on jsfiddle it scroll to second table. yes you're right and welcome